# Does Sitecore licensing affect API calls?

Tags: licensing

As I understand it, your Sitecore license limits how many content authors can be logged into Sitecore concurrently. If I were to write a web application that uses the Sitecore ItemService API to allow users on our intranet to manage data in Sitecore (e.g., user profile or product details), would those API calls count against the content author limit in the license?

For example, if my license allows a maximum of four content authors to be logged in simultaneously, would calls from the ItemService API be blocked from managing content in Sitecore?

Comment: I really think that this question cannot be answered. Depending on the kind of licenses, (is it standard, a tailormade license, or anything else?) the answers may vary. In addition, it's something information that could change over time, could change per version and maybe even per country. That's why it's dangerous to share the answers over here, as it might give wrong information to (potential) customers

Comment: Questions about licensing for Sitecore not allowed. Contact Sitecore for help.

Answer (score 4):

As I recall, a client from a while back wanted to have more content authors than they wanted to pay for content authoring licenses. (We're talking like 200+ authors).  So, they contracted the company I was working for to bulid a completely custom authoring app that allowed this to happen without having to login as Sitecore users.

So, as it stands to reason, I would say if you're building something that utilizes the ItemWeb API, and the users do not have to be logged into Sitecore as `sitecore` domain users, then you're probably safe.

**However, as a Sitecore Partner** I would yield to asking your Sitecore Inside Sales Account Manager for clarity.

EDIT: That's also based on the server instance licensing model.  Consumption based licensing is based on production CD visits, not users.

Comment: So with consumption-based licensing, an unlimited amount of Content Authors can be logged in concurrently?

Comment: Is there a chance that this varies depending on the type of licence you have and what version of Sitecore you are using also?

Comment: There is one big caveat for this tho. To edit the content, a user would be used, whether that is admin, anonymous or something else you have setup. So _all_ those editors would be under the same user account, so security and workflow and audit history would be seriously limited

Comment: All of these questions should probably be best asked to your Sales, Partner Rep, or coordinating implementation partner. I am only a Sitecore Partner,  and know that license costs can vary based on the solution as a whole.